# Mysql Query where max(time) less than today

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have two tables, the first table ( job ) stores the data and the second table ( job_locations ) stores the locations for each job, I'm trying to show the number of jobs that job locations are less than today

I use the DateTime for the Date Column

unfortunately, the numbers that appear after test the next code are wrong
My code

```
SELECT *
FROM `job`
left join job_location
    on job_location.job_id = job.id
where job_location.cutoff_time < CURDATE()
group by job.id
```

Please help me to write the working Query.

Comment: read mysql having()

Comment: No numbers appear. Perhaps that's why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to rephrase your query slightly.  Select a count of jobs where the cutoff time is earlier than the start of today.

```
SELECT
    j.id,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN jl.cutoff_time < CURDATE() THEN 1 END) AS cnt
FROM job j
LEFT JOIN job_location jl;
    ON j.id = jl.job_id
GROUP BY
    j.id;
```

Note that the left join is important here because it means that we won't drop any jobs having no matching criteria.  Instead, those jobs would still appear in the result set, just with a zero count.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: @AhmedZain . . . This actually isn't the best way to write the query.  The comparison should be in the `ON` clause, with a `COUNT()` in the `SELECT`.  If all jobs have at least one location, then you don't even need the `JOIN` for conditional aggregation.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . The query is a *correct* way to answer the question, it is just not the best way.

Answer (score 0):

As a note, you can simplify the count (in MySQL).  And, assuming that all jobs have at least one location, you don't need a `JOIN` at all.  So:

```
SELECT jl.job_id, sum( jl.cutoff_time < CURDATE() )
FROM job_location jl
GROUP BY jl.job_id;
```

If this is not correct (and you need the `JOIN`), then the condition on the date should go in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT jl.job_id, COUNT(jo.job_id)
FROM job LEFT JOIN
     job_location jl
     ON jl.job_id = j.id AND jl.cutoff_time < CURDATE()
GROUP BY jl.job_id;
```

Comment: I can't delete my post.  Well, at least my query gives the correct results.